# Typescript Type for window.matchMedia change event object

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

I listen to the `window.matchMedia` changes

I have this error: `Parameter 'event' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

What TS type should I specify here for the `event` object?

```
const mobileMediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 699px)");
mobileMediaQuery?.addEventListener("change", processViewSizeChange);

function processViewSizeChange(event) {
  console.log('media query changed! →', event.matches);
}
```

where on the internet to look up typescript global types? in case I need to find something similar in the future.

Comment: Maybe see [MediaQueryListEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryListEvent)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use TypeScript to learn about the types that you need. Here's an example in your case. You know that you need to supply the `"change"` event type, and that you need to supply a callback function for the listener, but you're not sure how to type the callback function, so just leave it out at first:

```ts
const mobileMediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 699px)');
mobileMediaQuery.addEventListener('change', ); /*               
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.(2554) */
```

If you don't include the second argument to `mobileMediaQuery.addEventListener`, you'll get a compiler error diagnostic like that.

But if you are using an IDE which includes the TypeScript Language Server and something like IntelliSense (e.g. [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), or the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)), you can mouse over the `addEventListener` method to see its signature:

```
(method) MediaQueryList.addEventListener<"change">(type: "change", listener: (this: MediaQueryList, ev: MediaQueryListEvent) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void (+1 overload)
```

As you can see from the signature, the `listener` is the second argument, and the type of the event parameter in the listener is `MediaQueryListEvent`. So you can type your listener function like this:

```ts
function processViewSizeChange(event: MediaQueryListEvent): void {
  console.log('media query changed! →', event.matches);
}
```

[Final code at TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtiARgSwDYFMCy6AmyCGAigK7oBOAnjALwwDuyYOIdAdHPlMABbZ74AKAOQCOADwC0DHFG4AuGADYAnMoAOYgJRDNAbgCwAKAQoMfAiXIVW+HDgCiAN3RgoAGWTQX5YT3xgAc3QhABoYNTIQYHQICAA1ZHQ6AGVkAC90AGFufyC9IyMAM2IwYChkcHDI6NiEpNSM7Nz0AXRnVwVzIlJKD2gnFyhNBUcQZBwYAG8jGBhQSBAMVlQQAOE4XAIYAEceqj9A3ABCGEAkwlCYNsH2Th4Y-MMAXyMgA)

Comment: Incredibly helpful answer! Thank you!